# Custom button animation using jquery and scss failing to stop

Tags: jquery

I have a button with two CSS animations.  The first animation rotates the button.  The second animation produces a "done" message.  However, the first animation continues to loop through.

I use jquery selectors to add an event listener to the button with a callback function passed to the click method that gives it the class on which the rotation animation is set.  Then after a 250 ms delay the function passed as the third argument into the 'addClass' method inside the callback should be called and that should remove this class and give it a 'validate' class.  This validate class should produce the 'done' message but the button continues to rotate indefinitely.

Also, can someone explain to me why the b tag is styled in CSS when there is no b tag in the HTML.  This code is part of an exercise and it is not clear to me why any styling has to be done on a b tag, and if there is a place I should place bold tags?

Can someone guide me as to where I have gone wrong here?

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  button id="button" class="btn btn1"> Submit</button>
</div>
```

The compiled CSS:

```
* {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; }

.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -65px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  width: 130px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center; }

.button {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 75px;
  color: #0099CC;
  /* Text color */
  background: transparent;
  /* Remove background color */
  border: 2px solid #0099CC;
  /* Border thickness, line style, and color */
  border-radius: 70px;
  /* Adds curve to border corners */
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  /* Make letters uppercase */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer; }

.button1 {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #008CBA; }

.button1:hover {
  background-color: #008CBA;
  color: white; }

b {
  outline: none;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 130px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #008CBA;
  color: #008CBA;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-shadow: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.25s ease; }
  b:active {
    letter-spacing: 2px; }
  b:after {
    content: ""; }

.onclic {
  width: 10px !important;
  height: 70px !important;
  border-radius: 50% !important;
  border-color: #bbbbbb;
  border-width: 4px;
  font-size: 0;
  border-left-color: #008CBA;
  animation: rotating 2s 0.25s linear infinite ; }
  .onclic:hover {
    color: dodgerblue;
    background: white; }

.validate {
  content: "";
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  background: dodgerblue;
  border-radius: 50px; }
  .validate:after {
    font-family: 'Verdana';
    content: " done \f00c"; }

@keyframes rotating {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg); }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg); } }
```

And the jQuery script:

```
$(function() {
  $("#buttons").click(function() {
    $("#buttons").addClass("onclic", 250, validate);
  });
function validate() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#buttons").removeClass("onclic");
      $("#buttons").addClass("validate", 450, callback);
    }, 2250);
  }
  function callback() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#buttons").removeClass("validate");
    }, 1250);
  }
});
```

Any feedback is appreciated!

Comment: First, the `addClass()` method accepts just one argument why you think you could pass three???

Comment: Check https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/rdgkfe31/

Answer (score 1):

I think at this point of your programming expertise, you should start to use the console.log and see what's going on when nothing works, but first, you need to provide good examples, because there is actually bugs in the code that should be improved, so let's start, first make it work:

the HTML button element is missing a code char:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <button id="button" class="btn btn1"> Submit</button>
</div>
```

Your JavaScript is calling "buttons" as ID:

```
$("#buttons").click(function() ...........
//Should be #button, because you don't have a group of buttons, you only have one
```

Definitely, the addClass method from jquery can only accept a class, or a function, you can check it out here:
https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

So then just add and remove classes as Zakaria said in the comments of your question, if you still would like to use some delay, you can always add addClass('validate').delay(450).

About the b element, browser clients treats that element the same as the strong tag, so it just basically adds a font-weight: bold; to it, other than that, I have a feeling that the "b" in your code is not a tag element, rather a class, so you have to put it as .b{ and assign it to your button element, like this:

```
<button id="button" class="btn btn1 b"> Submit </button>
```

and then in the CSS:

```
.b {
  outline: none;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 130px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #008CBA;
  color: #008CBA;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-shadow: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.25s ease; 
}
.b:active {
  letter-spacing: 2px; 
}
.b:after {
  content: ""; 
}
```

And then you will see the button now changing a bit, which is good, consequently you would like to merge several classes, for example changing class="btn btn1 b" into one class="buttonSubmit" and put all your styles for the button there.

Right now also button1 class in the CSS is not doing anything, so just change all your styles for that button into one single element CSS style, like so:

```
button{
  outline: none;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 130px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #008CBA;
  color: #008CBA;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-shadow: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.25s ease; 
}

button:active {
  letter-spacing: 2px; 
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #008CBA;
  color: white; 
}
```

Also if you have a content: "" in your main class "validate", and you have an after, it will take the second content: "", so I just removed the first one from the main class, not the after. One last thing, is to try and not to use !important at all in your CSS, if you need to put !important, is probably because the elements weren't prioritized correctly in the DOM.

Hope all of this helped.

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6rhgsvke/27/